# Is it possible to set snap settings?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the Autodesk Forge viewer v7 using the Edit2D tool.  This question is specifically about the snapping functionality.  It is currently working but a bit overzealous...  It seems to have all of the possible snaps on (endpoint, along line, intersections, centers, etc.).  It also seems to snap to layers that I have hidden.

Is there a way to set the snaps that are on and off?  Also is there a way to limit the layers that it snaps to? I was looking for possibly a method that will tell me the object(s) it's trying to snap to and the type of snap and let me determine if that's a viable snap point and return true/false or something like that but I couldn't find one.  Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**
I did find `setSnapFilter` but it doesn't seem to do anything.  I have this implementation in my code:

```
// @ts-ignore
e.defaultContext.snapper.sheetSnapper.setSnapFilter((e) => {
  console.log(e);
  return false;
});
```

However, I never get a console log happening.  I have tried this on both the sheet snapper and the layer snapper and I've tried returning both true and false and none of them are ever called or make any difference to the snapping.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch! The `context.snapper.sheetSnapper` object does have a `setSnapFilter` method you can override. Unfortunately, this filter is only invoked in the `Snapper#onMouseMove` method, and the `Edit2D` extension *bypasses* this method. That's why overriding the method has no effect. Let me pass this info to the engineering team for consideration.

Comment: Ok thank you.  It would be really nice to know a way around this if possible, or if the engineering team has an update or something that would fix it.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Hi there, the feedback from the engineering team is that currently the `snapFilter` is only meant for internal use (to prevent self-snapping). They will consider exposing the filtering for external use as well but it is not clear when that would be available as they have a lot of tasks with higher priority at the moment.